# Full Node Setup Questions- IPv6 & Using AWS As Static IP Service

Tags: iri-node, static-ip, aws

Two quick questions: I have an  IPv6 address. Does that matter at all when it comes to running a full node and other people's ability to connect to me?  Also I already use AWS for a few different things, which is why it would be preferable to NoIP, but I can't think of a simple way to go about updating my dynamic IP when it changes on AWS. Any ideas?